# JSON returns null

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am facing the problem in getting the variable value through getJSON. Here is the code the i am trying!
**display.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
            $.getJSON("code.php", function(data) {
      alert("Value for 'a': " + data.first + "\nValue for 'b': " + data.last);
    });
</script>

</body>                                                                                             
</html>
```

**code.php**

```
<?php    
$var1=$_REQUEST['id'];
$var2="Some hard codded text";
$output =  array('first'=>$var1,
                 'last'=>$var2);
echo json_encode($output,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

I am using alert(result) as well as the getJSON to check the value of the variable, alert(result) shows both the values but the getJSON returns "null" for ID value.

Comment: Your second AJAX request passes no parameter, so `data.first` will always be null/empty

Comment: It's also a bit weird to make the same AJAX call twice, right after each other.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake! thanks for pointing this! it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data parameter needs to be sent while calling $.getJSON
Use add data parameter as shown below code:

```
 $.getJSON("code.php", data, function(data) {
  alert("Value for 'a': " + data.first + "\nValue for 'b': " + data.last);
});
```

Comment: could you please post the code, i mean what could be the the structure now in my case? @ Karthik M R

Comment: why are you calling the same url onsuccess of 1st ajax?1st ajax also returns the same json data right?

Comment: yeah, got it working now! removed the above ajax request and kept the getJSON only, its working now! thanks  Karthik M R!

Comment: np. can you mark this answer as useful so it helps other people to directly check this out.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax() starts an ajax request and in the response of it, you start another ajax request with $.getJSON().

You can make one ajax call with:

```
$.getJSON("code.php", function(data) {
  alert("Value for 'a': " + data.first + "\nValue for 'b': " + data.last);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
  $.getJSON("code.php",data, function(jdata) {
  alert("Value for 'a': " + jdata.first + "\nValue for 'b': " + jdata.last);
});
```